# Why this dark mode toogle is working just with the background and not the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website with cargo collective and I need a dark mode toggle that switch the background color on click but ever the text color. For the moment is just working with the background and it's not affecting the text.

the toggle i'm using:

```
**<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}**
</script>
```

Css I wrote:

```
body {
    background-color:#d9ff76!important;
}
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black!important; 
    }
```

I'd like H1 and even all the text to be affected by the dark mode but inside > .dark-mode { I can't write H1 or p or whatever.

This is how cargo define H1:

```
[data-predefined-style="true"] h1 {
    font-family: "Le Murmure", Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 45rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    }
```

Does anyone knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this that would helps you write less CSS code is to to use `*` selector to make every element inherit the `body` color. And then if there is a need change for some specific element like so:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  color: inherit;
}
body {
  background-color: #d9ff76;
}
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode button {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
<h1>I'm a h1</h1>
<p>I'm a p</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually works but just if I write <button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
<h1>I'm a h1</h1>
<p>I'm a p</p> in the script section! If i write it in the code section of a specific page it's not affecting the text at all

Comment: Are you using something like Bootstrap? You have conflict issue I think. Try using `!important`.

Comment: Where should I use the !important? I've building the site with cargo collective and i'm just using the script I've show you

Comment: Try adding to all CSS properties.

Comment: Use the inspection tool to detect if there are some properties that are being overwritten. To understand how this works, see [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Comment: Hi @EmanuelePesa, can you tell if it did work ?

Comment: I've just tried and it worked!! Thank you so much (the problem was not to have the !important everywhere I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can determine what the color of elements is going to be, *if the class of body was some specific class*. For example, if you wanted your *h1* to be white, you can simply use the selector I did at the bottom. 
 Surely read this article about dark mode via [Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const el = document.querySelector('.el');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.classList.toggle('dark');
})
```

```css
.el {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #121212
}

/* Important */
.dark h1 {
  color: #f0f0f0
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
<div class="el">
  <h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should I write the first part of the code? const btn.. I've never used that! Should it be inside the script?

Comment: Yes, the variable name I used is related to ES6 which you should learn ES. You can just copy-paste the js code in the script tag.

Comment: So my code should look like that:
<div>This is a div element.</div>
<script>
  
  
function myFunction() {
   const element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
  
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const el = document.querySelector('.el');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.classList.toggle('dark');
})

</script>